# Why does `/\:/u` throw an “invalid escape” error?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have code like this:

```js
url.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/:?#]+)(?:[\/:?#]|$)/ui)
```

ESLint says `Parsing error: Invalid regular expression: /^https?\:\/\/([^\/:?#]+)(?:[\/:?#]|$)/: Invalid escape`.

I don’t see why this regular expression is wrong. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

### Unnecessary escape sequences are invalid with the `u` flag

`\:` is an unnecessary escape sequence. Those are *invalid* when using the `u` flag. Just use `:` instead.

### Specification, debuggers, documentation

These are the valid and necessary escape sequences of special characters outside of character classes: `\$`, `\(`, `\)`, `\*`, `\+`, `\.`, `\?`, `\[`, `\\`, `\]`, `\^`, `\{`, `\|`, `\}` (all [“syntax characters”](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-SyntaxCharacter)), and `\/` (special case of an [identity escape](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-IdentityEscape)).

Other escape sequences like `\` , `\!`, `\"`, `\#`, `\%`, `\&`, `\'`, `\,`, `\-`, `\:`, `\;`, `\<`, `\=`, `\>`, `\@`, `\_`, `` \` ``, `\~` are unnecessary and thus invalid with the `u` flag.

Look into the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-AtomEscape) for all the escaping rules in detail.<sup>1</sup>

---

Tools like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) report this — a bit cryptic, though:

> `/\:/u`:
>
> `\:` — This token has no special meaning and has thus been rendered erroneous

---

As for documentation, I have *just now* added a note in the [regex cheat sheet on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet):

> Note that some characters like `:`, `-`, `@`, etc. neither have a special meaning when escaped nor when unescaped.
> Escape sequences like `\:`, `\-`, `\@` will be equivalent to their literal, unescaped character equivalents in regular expressions.
> However, in regular expressions with the [unicode flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2), these will cause an *invalid identity escape* error.

### Rationale

The note continues:

> This is done to ensure backward compatibility with existing code that uses new escape sequences like `\p` or `\k`.

When the feature was proposed and introduced, this is what the [proposal’s FAQ](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes#what-about-backwards-compatibility) had to say:

> #### What about backwards compatibility?
>
> In regular expressions without the `u` flag, the pattern `\p` is an (unnecessary) escape sequence for `p`.
> Patterns of the form `\p{Letter}` might already be present in existing regular expressions without the `u` flag, and therefore we cannot assign new meaning to such patterns without breaking backwards compatibility.
>
> For this reason, ECMAScript 2015 made unnecessary escape sequences like `\p` and `\P` [throw an exception](https://tc39.es/archives/bugzilla/3157/) when the `u` flag is set.
> This enables us to change the meaning of `\p{…}` and `\P{…}` in regular expressions with the `u` flag without breaking backwards compatibility.

This page is also linked from this [ES Discuss thread](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/why-is-regexp-u-a-syntax-error) where this question has been raised:

> #### Why is RegExp `/\-/u` a syntax error?
>
> JSLint previously warned against unescaped literal `-` in RegExp.
> However, escaping `-` together with unicode flag `u` causes a syntax error in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge (and JSLint has since removed the warning).
> Just curious about the reason why the above edge-case is a syntax error.
>
> *(Minor grammar adjustments by me.)*

The responses link to the above GitHub repo with the proposal, but also explain the rationale in a different way:

> Think of the `u` flag as a strict mode for regular expressions.

So, whenever you use the `u` flag, keep this in mind.
RegExps begin to behave a little differently as soon as you use `u`.
Certain new things become valid, but certain other things become invalid, too.
For example, also see [Why is `/[\w-+]/` a valid regex but `/[\w-+]/u` invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54205197/4642212).

---

<sup>1</sup>: You’ll find certain production rules with `[U]` which is a parameter that represents Unicode patterns.
See the [grammar notation reference](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-grammar-notation) for decoding these.